# ASP.NET MVC running IIS7 deployment problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I am having trouble deploying an ASP.NET MVC app to IIS7.

I have an MVC project created with ASP.NET MVC Beta 1. It consists of nothing more than the default template unmodified.

The app runs just fine within VS2008, but when I publish it to a local IIS7 website (http://localhost), I get the following server error:

> The incoming request does not match any route

I have also tried unsuccessfully to access http://localhost/Home/About (a route to a specific page within the template). This returns a 404 error.

I have recreated the website in IIS several times and ensured the pipeline mode is set to integrated. My IIS7 server is running on my Vista Home Premium machine.

I am assuming this is an IIS configuration issue any suggestions as to configuration issues with ASP.NET MVC apps would be appreciated.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is IIS 7 in integrated or Classic mode? Can you publish more info about your configuration? Is it a root website or is it in a virtual application?

Answer (score 3):

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx

This solved all my problems.

Answer (score 2):

Does IIS run ok with the default IIS7 site?

Are you receiving any Event Viewer messages?

Comment: I have a number of asp.net(not MVC) sites successfully running on this machine. The message suggests to me it is originating from the routing feature.

Comment: Copy n paste the error messages online so we can see them to help u find an answer

Answer (score 2):

Is IIS in Integrated Mode? If it's not, you'll have to do some setup or change it to Integration Mode

Comment: yes you are right. I have written an answer which contains a blog post explaining how to do those setups.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you are running under IIS 7.0 Integrated mode. If you need to run it under IIS 7.0 Classic mode, you need to perform several actions to make the routes work. Please refer the following blog posts;

[http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/running-asp-net-mvc-under-iis-6-0-and-iis-7-0-classic-mode---solution-to-routing-problem](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/47)

[http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/deployment-of-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2-application-on-a-shared-hosting-environment-without-begging-the-hosting-company](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/39)

Comment: Thanks that helped me out (I'm having to work with IIS7 in Classic mode)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install these software requirements:

- AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup
- wpilauncher_3_10(Select: Application Request Routing 2.5)