# Move from Dev Server to Prod Server - The incoming request does not match any route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have developed an app on a dev machine using ASP.Net MVC and all is fine and it works. I have moved it to the Prod Server and when I type http://mydomain.com I get the error:

*The incoming request does not match any route*

If I then make a request to http://mydomain.com/pagename I then get a IIS 7 404 page.

It is hosted in a Full Trust Mode and Integrated Pipeline according to Softsys hosting who its hosted with.

I am currently accessing the site via a temporary DNS name eg/http://mydomain.com.serv7.temphostspace.com and my host believes this might be it.

From the support ticket this is what they say *"I believe, this is caused since you are access your website through temporary URL http://mdomain.com.serv7.temphostspace.com/ and relevant setting might be missing in your configuration."

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was trust issues not configured right

Answer (score 0):

Your host is probably barking up the wrong tree, unless the site isn't configured. I'd try and request a static file you know is there to be certain. As for the problem at hand, how are you wiring up the routes? Could something in production be failing before this and prevent this from happening?

Anyhow, first place I would start is by using the [ASP.NET Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to see what routes your app thinks it has.

Comment: Thanks.  I have done a request for a file I know exists test.htm and that gets rendered ok

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem: [ASP.NET MVC running IIS7 deployment problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213774/iis7-asp-net-mvc-deployment-problem)

Resolution from there: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx

Comment: I have put the MVC dll in the bin directory only as I'm informed that 3.5 SP1 is installed on the server and still no luck